# Typescript ignores extra properties on return type of setState function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, setstate, typechecking

I'm at wits end here. Why does typescript allow me to return essentially anything in the `setFormValidation` call, so long as I provide the prevState spread in the return object? It ignores all other properties I return in the object, even though `ValidationPayload` is the only type allowed on my mapped type. `test: 6` is not in `ValidationPayload`.

Am I doing something wrong in my typing of `useState`? Is this beyond typescripts capabilities? Even if I cast the return type `as FormValidationState<T>` it still ignores it. Thank you.

```js
export interface ValidationPayload {
  isInvalid: boolean;
  error: string[];
}

export type FormValidationState<T extends string> = {
  [key in T | 'form']: ValidationPayload;
}

export function useFormValidation<T extends string>(keys: T[]) {

  function initFormValidation(keys: T[]): FormValidationState<T> {
    const initState = {} as FormValidationState<T>;
    keys.forEach((key: T) => {
      initState[key] = {
        isInvalid: false,
        error: [], // type checking here works
      };
    });

    initState.form = { isInvalid: false, error: [] };
    return initState;
  }

  const [formValidation, setFormValidation] = useState<FormValidationState<T>>(
    () => initFormValidation(keys),
  );

  setFormValidation((prevState: FormValidationState<T>) => {
    return {
      ...prevState,
      test: 6 // this should throw a ts error
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Typescript is structurally typed. You can *always* have extra properties.

Answer (score 0):

I think the short answer here is `setFormValidation` call is of type "(prevState: FormValidationState) => any". Easiest way to check would be to hover over the function and see the return type for yourself.

Suggested refactor:

```
export interface ValidationPayload {
  isInvalid: boolean;
  error: string[];
}

export type FormValidationState = Record<string, ValidationPayload>

export function useFormValidation(keys: string[]): FormValidationState {
  const [formValidation, setFormValidation] = 
useState<FormValidationState>(initFormValidation(keys)); //Hooks always at the top of function body
  

  setFormValidation((prevState) => (
    {
      ...prevState,
      //...code
    }
  ))
}
```

In its current version, this piece can be anywhere in the file:

```
function initFormValidation(keys: string[]): FormValidationState {
    const initState: FormValidationState = {}
    keys.forEach((key) => {
      initState[key] = {
        isInvalid: false,
        error: [],
      };
    });

    initState.form = { isInvalid: false, error: [] }; //Not recommended
    //better to test overall form state elsewhere to avoid data overlap

    return initState;
  }
```

I'd just throw it in a constants folder or around the bottom of file.